# Mongoose findByID from URL route parameter not working with Express router

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I saw this in a tutorial but can't make it work:

```
/* GET one item. */
router.get('/items/:id', (req, res) => {
  Item.findById(req.param.id, (err, items) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(error)

    res.status(200).json(items);
  });
});
```

I also tried "`.findById({_id: req.params.id}`"

I always get the whole list of items.
I can not find the proper way to implement `findById` from the documentation with `router.get`

Comment: Shouldn't that be [`req.params.id`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) instead? [`req.param`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.param) is a (deprecated) function.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. With my version "req.params.id" actually worked. Although, in a tutorial it was "req.param.id". The problem in my case was, that the URL: '/items/:id' was conflicting with another get method with the URL: '/items', which was fetching all of the items. So I renamed it to '/item/:id'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in my case was, that the URL: `'/items/:id'` was conflicting with another get method with the URL: `'/items'`, which was fetching all of the items. So I renamed it to `'/item/:id'`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Item.findById, try to use Item.find({id:req.params.id}

```
/* GET one item. */
router.get('/items/:id', (req, res) => {
   Item.find({id:req.params.id}, (err, items) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(error)

    res.status(200).json(items);
  });
});
```